# Pass parameter from a view to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I essentially want to be able to pass a parameter to a view (which works) which will then be able to be passed further to a controller if the user presses a `<a>` link (which does not work as intended).

My initial view is defined as:

```
@model IEnumerable<Path.To.MyClass>
// Do stuff....
<a asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="MyView" asp-route-myProducts = "Model">Update</a>
```

Where my MyView within MyController is defined as:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult MyView(IEnumerable<MyClass> myProducts)
{
//Insert a breakpoint 
}
```

Essentially I don't get any errors, but within the view in which I have my  link myProducts has a bunch of elements. However when I access the breakpoint within MyView myProducts is empty.

Does anyone know what the issue may be?

I've tried to use `[HttpPost]` instead of `[HttpGet]` for MyView, but I seemed to have gotten an infinite loop when I ran the program using IIS Express then.

EDIT
I've tried

`<input type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("MyView", "MyController", Model)'">Update</button>`

now as well with the same issue (the parameter for the controller is empty without any errors).

EDIT2:
I've also tried making a new class like this:

```
public class ProductList
{
    List<MyClass> products {get;set;}
}
```

And consequently replaced the MyView parameter to be `ProductList myProducts` instead of `IENumerable<MyClass> myProdcuts`. In the `@url.Action` within the view I've tried to use `<input type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("MyView", "MyController", Model.AsList())'">Update</button>` as well. This gives the same issue (i.e. no error, but no elements within ProductList myProducts in my controller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a list with `<a></a>`,you can try to serialize the model in view,and then deserialize the data to the model in action.Here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class ProductList
    {
        public List<MyClass> products { get; set; }
    }
    public class MyClass 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

MyView1.cshtml:

```
@model Path.To.ProductList
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
<a href=@Url.Action("MyView","Test1",new {myProducts = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model) })>Update</a>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult MyView1()
        {
            ProductList l = new ProductList { products = new List<MyClass> { new MyClass { Id = 1, Name = "class1" }, new MyClass { Id = 2, Name = "class2" }, new MyClass { Id = 3, Name = "class3" } } };
            return View(l);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult MyView(string myProducts)
        {
            ProductList p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductList>(myProducts);
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked with some minor tweaks (most notably in MyView I changed ```JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductList>(productList);``` to ```JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(productList);```. As a side note; how did you make a gif of the solution? Using OBS Studio?

Comment: You can search in browser,there will be many free programs which can record the screen and save as a gif.

Answer (score 1):

I will give an example of the general logic of posting information.

In the example I give, I pass a list of products to the controller.

**model classes**

```
public class ProductList
{
    List<Product> products { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
   public int ID { set; get; }
   public string ProductName { set; get; }
}
```

**in controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult MyView()
{
    var model = new ProductList();
    model.products = new List<Product>();
    Viewbag.Count = 5;
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyView(ProductList model)
{
   foreach(Product item in model.products)
   {
     //do somethings
   }
   Viewbag.Count = 5;
   return View(model);
}
```

**in view**

```
@model yournamespace.ProductList
@{ 
   ViewBag.MTitle = "my view"; 
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
} 

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyView", "controllername", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"})) { 
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  @for(var i = 0; i < Viewbag.Count; i++) {
        <div class="row">
           >@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].ID)
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].ProductName)
        </div>
    }
    <div class="row">
       <button class="btn-control">add</button>
    </div>
}
```